# What steps need to be taken to implement OpenCL on a device?

Tags: assembly, compilation, opencl, specifications, spir-v

Lets say I have a device which, while it has the capability to support, does not currently support OpenCL.  I have the ISA, the hardware design documents and a lot of other documentation.   My system which the device is located on currently has C and C++ compilers and has support for many linux distributions.

Now I want to add OpenCL (lets say the latest version, 2.2) support to my device.  What do I actually need to do in order to have my device supported?  I see documentation for SPIR-V on their site, ie: [SPIR-V registry page](https://www.khronos.org/registry/spir-v/#spec), [opencl extended instruction set overview](https://www.khronos.org/registry/spir-v/specs/1.2/OpenCL.ExtendedInstructionSet.100.pdf), [normal spir-V overview](https://www.khronos.org/registry/spir-v/specs/1.2/SPIRV.pdf).

Now lets say I do implement a SPIR-V-to-my-device-ISA compiler, do I now support OpenCL 2.2?  I see [another registry for OpenCL](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/) but I don't see a thing that says "if you implement these functions, write code that does this etc.. you now have implemented the OpenCL 2.2 specification on your system".

What are the actual steps I need to take in order to implement OpenCL for my device?

Answer (score 1):

Well you have to provide an implementation of the open cl api. This api implementation needs to efficiently compile opencl kernels for your architecture.

To support a certain set of features (meaning OpenCL versions and extensions) you will need to support certain features in the api and the opencl c /c++ kernel language. All these things are specified in the open cl standard which you can find on the [khronos website](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/specs/).

For simplifying the whole process companies like intel,nvidia,amd,... all base their compiler on LLVM. If you need to further reduce the effort having a look at POCL might also be an option.

Does your system have a custom architecture or is it just a custom software stack?

Comment: Would I not be supporting opencl kernels by supporting compilation to SPIR-V with opencl extensions?  I thought those kernels were compiled to SPIR-V as of 2.0.  I'm writing this for a GPU which doesn't have opencl specifications on a SOC. as far as I know there is no LLVM to this GPUs assembly.   I'm confused on how to make something that supports OpenCL.   Do I just write a compiler from SPIR-V or LLVM to my assembly?  The cpu on my SOC I believe already supports OpenCL, this is just a seperate device on the same board that doesn't.  What is the step to allow host cl to access device?

Comment: You also need runtime features, just a compiler is probably not enough. Like @Dithermaster also said, starting with POCL is probably your safest bet. Unfortunately they all use llvm in some form or another.

Answer (score 0):

I would start with **pocl** and add a backend (http://portablecl.org/). Everything else has already been done.